# I get huge bandwidth transfer from some unknown bot Unknown robot (identified by 'bot*')

Tags: htaccess, bandwidth

I get huge bandwidth transfer from some unknown bot Unknown robot (identified by 'bot*').There are ways to block it via htaccess or other means. The question is whether to block it for website safety or it is the good that search engines are crawing the website.

I am very new to website designing so don't know the basics. Please guide me if i have to block them or let it be like this

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to figure out if this bot reads `robots.txt`. You can define a `crawl-delay` in there for this bot. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377835/robots-txt-what-is-the-proper-format-for-a-crawl-delay-for-multiple-user-agent) goes in more detail about what you have to do. You can disallow this bot to crawl your site via there too. Please note that rogue bots do not read, or simply ignore, `robots.txt` and that changes to this file might not work.

If you want to block a rogue bot the hard way, figure out it's ip. You can use `mod_authz_host` in `.htaccess` to hard-block this ip. You can do this with the following code:

```
<Directory />
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from 127.0.0.1
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The xml-like-tags around this code say that these rules are valid for the `/` directory (root). If a request is processed, it will process all rules for that directory and all rules for any parent directory that directory has. (so: A request to `/asdf/` will eventually parse these rules too.

`Order Deny,Allow` tells Apache to process all 'deny' rules first, then all allow rules. `Deny from 127.0.0.1`, will block all requests to `127.0.0.1`. Needless to tell that you should change this ip to the real ip. `Allow from all` will allow everyone else access. This will present that bot with a `Forbidden` error I believe.

More information about mod_authz_host can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html) and more information about the `<directory>` directive can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory).